# pattern matching in ruby

Tags: ruby

cud any body tell me how this expression works

```
output = "#{output.gsub(/grep .*$/,'')}"
```

before that opearation value of ouptput is

```
"df -h | grep /mnt/nand\r\n/dev/mtdblock4  248.5M    130.7M    117.8M  53% /mnt/nand\r\n"
```

but after opeartion it comes

```
"df -h | \n/dev/mtdblock4          248.5M 248.5M    130.7M    117.8M  53% /mnt/nand\r\n "
```

plzz help me

Comment: use `\`` so that we can tell text apart from code

Comment: What's the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: jamie i do n't have any expectation but i want to know this expression worksi understand up to like how grep is  replaced  by "" string but how it is working .*$ that i don't understand

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is equivalent to:

```
output.gsub!(/grep .*$/,'')
```

which is much easier to read.

The . in the regular expression matches all characters except newline by default. So, in the string provided, it matches "grep /mnt/nand", and will substitute a blank string for that. The result is the provided string, without the matched substring.

Here is a simpler example:

```
"hello\n\n\nworld".gsub(/hello.*$/,'') => "\n\n\nworld"
```

In both your provided regex, and the example above, the $ is not necessary. It is used as an anchor to match the end of a line, but since the pattern immediately before it (.*) matches everything up to a newline, it is redundant (but does not cause harm).

Comment: THANKS jason
but cud u plzz expain with some other example

Comment: and one more thing jason why this *$ is used plus /n is also at the end of line

Comment: @amit : I've updated the answer to include another example and an explanation of $ (and why it's not needed here). Think of the .* going together and the $ as a separate symbol.

Comment: nd one thing more will it these \n\n\\n in o/p
i think it will o/p as world

Comment: The newlines "\n\n\n" will remain, because they are not matched by the regex. The (.*) matches up to, but not including, a newline character. Notice in your original string, that the \n remains. Everything up to and including the \r is stripped (\r is not considered newline)

Answer (score 0):

Since gsub returns a string, your first line is exactly the same as

```
output = output.gsub(/grep .*$/, '')
```

which takes the string and removes any occurance of the regexp pattern

```
/grep .*$/
```

i.e. all parts of the string that start with 'grep ' until the end of the string or a line break.

Comment: thanks ULM line break means 
this /r or /n thats the line break??
nd why *$ is used

Comment: The exact definition of line break is implementation and platform dependent, but \n is definitely a line break. Regular expressions usually stop when they encounter the \n, unless you explicitely tell them otherwise.

.* means 'match any character zero or more times'. So anything after the 'grep ' is matched.

$ in the RegExp is a special character representing the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good regexp tester/reference [here](http://www.rubyxp.com/). This one matches the word "grep", then a space, then any number of characters until the next line-break (\r or \n). "." by itself means any character, and ".*" together means any number of them, as many as possible. "$" means the end of a line.

Comment: glenn thanks first of all
cud u plzz expain this .* that i m nt able to unstand yet
plzz i m waiting

Comment: A period by itself means any character, and an asterisk after anything means as many of those as possible. So put together ".*" gets everything on the rest of the line after the "grep ".

Answer (score 0):

For the '$', see here  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

".*$" means "take every character from the *end* of the string" ; but the parser will interpret the "\n" as the end of a line, so it stops here.